# Mysql what if too much data in a table

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Data is increasing in one table everyday, it might lower the performance . I was thinking if I can create a trigger which move table A into A1 and create a new table A every a period of time, so that insert or update could be faster in table A. Is this the right way to save performance ? If not, what should I do ?
(for example, insert or update 1000 rows per second in table A, how is the performance after 3 years ?)

We are designing softwares for a factory. There are product lines which pcb boards are made on. We need to insert almost 60 pcb records per second for years. (1000 rows seem to be exaggerated)

Comment: If you continuously insert 1000 new records per second in a table for years, you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Havenard:  Not necessarily.  I designed systems in the 1980s which record a material processing plant's data (thousands of sensors:  speed, pressure, opacity, temperature, chemical properties, etc.) and save it for analysis.  Initially 2200 points recorded every 60 seconds.  Each minute one record is saved—forever.  By now they would have likely increased the scan rate because it is more feasible and cost effective.  There should be *at least* 46 million rows by now.  The primary index is timestamp which *every* query of the data bounds.

Comment: @wallyk That is still quite manageable, certainly a lot more than 60000 new records per minute.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are talking about several terabytes for a single table.  Is your disk that big?  Yes, MySQL can handle that big a table.

Will it slow down?  It depends on

- The indexes.  If you have 'random' indexes, the `INSERTs` will slow down to about 1 insert per disk hit.  On a spinning HDD, that is only about 100 per second.  SSD *might* be able to handle 1000/sec.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.
- Does the table have an `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  If so, it needs to be `BIGINT`, not `INT`.  But, if possible, get rid of it all together (to save space).  Again, let's see the `SHOW`.
- "Point" queries (load one row via an index) are mostly unaffected by the size of the table.  They will be about twice as slow in a trillion-row table as in a million-row table.  A point query will take milliseconds or tens of milliseconds; no big deal.
- A table scan will take hours or days; hopefully you are not doing that.
- A billion-row scan of part of the table will take days or weeks unless you are using the `PRIMARY KEY` or have a "covering" index.  Let's see the queries and the `SHOW`.

The best technique is not to store the data.  Summarize it as it arrives, save the summaries, then toss the raw data.  (OK, you might store the raw in a csv file just in case you need to build a new summary table or fix a bug in an existing one.)

Having a few summary tables *instead of* the raw data would shrink the data to under 1TB and allow the relevant queries to run 10 times as fast.  (OK, point queries would be only slightly faster.)

`PARTITIONing` (or otherwise splitting up the table)?  It depends.  Let's see the queries and the `SHOW`.  In many situations, `PARTITIONing` does not speed up anything.

Will you be deleting or modifying existing rows?  I hope not.  That adds more dimensions of problems.  If, on the other hand, you need to purge 'old' data, then that is an excellent use for `PARTITIONing`.  For 3 years' worth of data, I would `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(..))` and have monthly partitions.  Then a monthly `DROP PARTITION` would be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Very Huge data may decrease the performance of server, So there is a way to handle this :

1) you have to create another table to store archive data ( old data ) using Archive storage mechanism . ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html )

2) create MySQL job/scheduler to move older records to archive table. schedule in timeslot 
 when server is maximum idle.

3) after moving older records to archive table, re-index the original table.

this will serve the purpose of performance.

Comment: for re-index table you have to follow Optimize table statement like : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: is there any standard guideline to perform archive? or simply move old rows to an archive table and optimize the original table in sufficient?

Comment: @SayedUzZaman, 
1) given steps are sufficient for this process, another way is partition.
2) you can do the partitioning of huge sized table, see : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179483/best-practice-to-archive-old-data-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that 1000 row tables perform sufficiently poorly that doing a table copy every once in a while is an overall net gain.  And anyway, what would the new table have that the old one did not which would improve performance?

The key to having tables perform efficiently is intelligent table design and management of indexes.  That is how zillion row tables are effective in geospatial work, library catalogs, astronomy, and how internet search engines find useful data, etc.

Each index defined does cause more mysql impact especially at row insert time.  Assuming there are more reads than inserts, this is an advantage because most queries are rapidly completed thanks to a suitable index.

Indexes are best defined with a thorough understanding of the queries made against the table—both in quality and quantity.  And, if there is any tendency for the nature of the queries to trend over months or years, then the indexes would need additions, modifications, or—yes—even deletions.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me there is something inherently wrong with the way you are using MySQL to begin with.

A database system is supposed to manage data that is required by your application in order for it to work. If you think flushing the table every so often is something acceptable, then that doesn't seem to be the case.

Perhaps you are better off just using log files. Split them by date, delete old ones if and when you decide they are no longer relevant or need the disk space. It's even safer to do that way from a recovery perspective.

If you need a better suggestion, then improve your question to include exactly what you are trying to accomplish so we can help you with it.

Comment: We are designing softwares for a factory. There are product lines which pcb boards are made on. We need to insert almost 60 pcb records per second for years. (1000 rows seem to be exaggerated). You said 'Split them by date' , is that means split one table into multiple by date  or  index by date ? Besides, can you be more specific about ' log files' ? Thanks